# How to use method in a method in react class component

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project where I need class component, but I am not experienced with classes. The problem I have is a method which I need to use in another method.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { face: 2 };
  }

  res(meshes) { 1 method
    return meshes.findIndex((e) => {
      return e.name === 'front';
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.face); //2
  }

  onSceneReady(scene) { 2 method
     modelMesh = meshes[this.res(meshes)]; //'Unable to load from /scenes/mesh.glb Cannot read proper`ties of undefined (reading 'res')'
     
     modelMesh = meshes[this.state.face]; //'Unable to load from /scenes/mesh.glb Cannot read proper`ties of undefined (reading 'state')
  }
```

I cannot use props, state and method inside 2. method which does all the job in the component.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.modelMesh = this.meshes[...]` ? Currently the `modelMesh` and `meshes` variables do not exist in `onSceneReady`.

Comment: @Kokodoko, modelMesh is let varaible in the onSceneReady method. meshes is a parametar from a function. So I call them without this because they are declared in method, meshes is just passed. The main problem I have which I dont uderstan is I cannot use anythink inside methods, but in render everythink works

Comment: Can you share the whole class? (well, minus JSX) Where is `onSceneReady` called from?

Comment: You can see it here on line 74 https://github.com/petrovic23/simulation/blob/main/src/Components/Babylon/Model.js

Comment: The reason is probably that you have a lot of `function` inside another `function`. At that point, the keyword `this` no longer refers to the main class, so you cannot get to the state anymore by using `this.state`. You can always double-check by putting `console.log(this)` at several points in your code.

Comment: You could start with trying to untangle nested functions into class methods, and when you really need the nested function, convert it into an arrow function, for example `onPointerDown = () => {}`

Comment: I found another way to work in babylon js. I had big problem but since I couldnt solve this one I found another way. Thanks you for helping however.